# get first and last column with pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My dataframe looks like as follow:

```
no        date            status   row_ant
1    11 Jan 2023, 07.00      ANT      1
1    11 Jan 2023, 09.00      AU       2
1    12 Jan 2023, 12.00      DLV      3
2    14 Jan 2023, 09.00      BA       1
2    14 Jan 2023, 10.00      AU       2
2    15 Jan 2023, 10.00      ANT      3 
3    15 Jan 2023, 09.00      ANT      1
3    16 Jan 2023, 10.00      AU       2
3    16 Jan 2023, 10.00      ANT      3
```

Each `no` has at least 2 rows in the dataframe which shows the history status by timestamps. Each row has timestamp, status, and also row number.

What I want to do is to create a summary where shows:

- the first date and the first status where status = ANT and row_ant = 1
- the last date and the last status whatever the value is

The desired result would be something like this:

```
no         date_ant        first_status   date_last_status    last_status
1    11 Jan 2023, 07.00        ANT        12 Jan 2023, 12.00     DLV
3    15 Jan 2023, 09.00        ANT        16 Jan 2023, 10.00     ANT
```

so far what I have done is to take the minimum and the maximum date only

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['no','status','row_ant'])
                .agg({'date':['min','max']})
                    .rename(columns={'min':'date_ant','max':'date_last_status'})).reset_index()
```

but this one does not return the status for `date_ant` and `date_last_status`.

How should I write my script to get the desired dataframe in pandas? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert column `date` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and if necessary sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) in both solutions.

Then filter last rows by `no` with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask and columns names in list. For `df2` filter by mask with conditions.
Last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %b %Y, %H.%M')
df = df.sort_values(['no','date'])

df1 = df.loc[~df.duplicated('no', keep='last'), ['no','date', 'status']]
df2 = df.loc[df['status'].eq('ANT') & df['row_ant'].eq(1),['no','date', 'status']]

df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', suffixes=('_first','_last'), on='no')
print (df)
   no          date_first status_first           date_last status_last
0   1 2023-01-11 07:00:00          ANT 2023-01-12 12:00:00         DLV
1   3 2023-01-15 09:00:00          ANT 2023-01-16 10:00:00         ANT
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for last `date` with change order of rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %b %Y, %H.%M')
df = df.sort_values(['no','date'])

df11 = df.iloc[::-1]
df1 = df11.loc[df11.groupby('no')['date'].idxmax(), ['no','date', 'status']]
df2 = df.loc[df['status'].eq('ANT') & df['row_ant'].eq(1),['no','date', 'status']]

df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', suffixes=('_first','_last'), on='no')
print (df)
   no          date_first status_first           date_last status_last
0   1 2023-01-11 07:00:00          ANT 2023-01-12 12:00:00         DLV
1   3 2023-01-15 09:00:00          ANT 2023-01-16 10:00:00         ANT
```